# QPJ Files missing

Tags: qgis, shapefile, save, files

So i have these shapefiles which i got for a thesis, a shapefile layer with 6 files.[image]

And i tried to make a shapefile layer where i crop the district from the old layer and pasted it in the new layer. Btw i'm using QGIS 3.16. But i noticed that i'm missing the .shp file[image]

Is there anyway to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing the .SHP it's the one with the file type of "AutoCAD Shape S..."
You need to deactivate your system setting that hide the known file extension to see the .SHP after the file name

Comment: Ohh i see. Thx for the help. I got really confused since i tried redoing it 4 times and kept on not getting the.shp file

Comment: turning on show file extensions will help with this too